# Is it correct and natural to say "what chance do you give to..."?

Tags: phrases, questions, phrase-choice

Could you tell me if it's correct and natural to say *what chance do you give to...* meaning what do you think is the chance of something happening? For example:

> Person A: **What chance do you give to** the pandemic being over by the summer?
>
> Person B: I give it a 100 percent chance.

If that is not the most natural way to ask that, what is most natural then?

Comment: I don't think *What chance do you give* is particularly "natural" for Anglophones when asking for a specific numerical "likelihood" value in this way (whether expecting some "percentage" between **0%** and **100%**, or a "fractional" value like **a one-in-five** chance). We tend to phrase such questions as ***How likely is it** that X will happen?*,  ***How likely** [do you think] **it is** that X will happen?* or ***What** [do you think] **are the chances** that X will happen?*

Comment: Do you want a percentage as an answer?  Or would you like odds?  The "do you give" portion of your query might indicate that you might be asking what a person might bet, and if that's what you are after "What odds would you give on the pandemic being over by summer?" would be natural.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I'd like a percentage as an answer. If want a percentage for an answer, will "what odds would you give on" work?

Comment: No, if you ask "What odds would you give?" your answer will be something like "twenty to one". To get a percentage, I think you'd have to ask for it. More natural would be to say "On a scale of one to ten, how likely do you think...?"

Comment: It's completely understandable and a common way to ask the question.  You may not get a *percentage* as the answer.  Answers could include *none, slim, fifty fifty, pretty good, or seventy three percent, etc.* depending on who is answering.  And, depending on who is answering, you may never get a percentage back no matter how you ask the question.  My mother would not provide a percentage unless you added something like, *and I'm looking for a percentage like 40 percent or 80 percent.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'to' or 'for' would be fine. Either doesn't read as odd to me.

> How likely is it that the pandemic is over by summer?

or

> What are the chances for the pandemic being over by the summer?

as options, but not "better".  Chance vs chances ... I think both can be used provided verb agreement is handled.
I like your wording a little better than any of mine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer? I wanted to clearify something. So "what chance do you give to the pandemic being over?" sounds all right to you, am I right?

Comment: No. (See my comment above! :)

Comment: Asking for a numeric "chance" doesn't make sense in English when there aren't hard facts to calculate an actual fact-based chance.  A yes/no question would be just as valid or a scaled not likely at all --- neutral --- highly likely if you want someone to guess.